# PyTorch BERT: multiclass sentiment classification accuracy is very low

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, multiclass-classification

I'm currently facing hard times training a BERT-based architecture myself on GoEmotions dataset for multiclass sentiment classification, with pytorch framework.
My main problem is that **accuracy is very low (average 0.40) on train/val set and does not increase** across epochs, whereas loss doesn't decrease.

[Screenshot to training metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMsZt.png)

What I can't explain to myself is how trained models in the tutorials started from an accuracy of 85% since the very first epoch, whereas mine doesn't.
Amongst my attempts, I've tried the following with no success at all:

- change the architecture by adding another Linear layer
- drop one-hot-encoded labels in favor of serialized labels (1, 0, 2, 0, ...)
- change the learning rate and other parameters (batch size, tokenizer max length, ...)
- make sure the loss function is correct, the gradients do get cleared out before updating, ...
- make sure dataset is balanced
- change the dataframe to another one, maybe who knows something I didn't see is wrong in the data
- ...and much more.

I would be VERY thankful to whoever can help me and/or give hints about this problem which is affecting my working since a week or so.

I'm pasting here:

- the link to the custom functions that I've developed and used (likely the mistake is here, sigh): https://github.com/D1996B/myprojects/blob/master/scripts/BERT%20classification/BertClassification.py
- the link to the colaboratory notebook with outputs, to see the steps: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZMFkhA2Qagln__dc0qeVhpN4P3YjaXc4

Please do let me know whether links are not accessible.
I would like to thank prior whoever puts his head into this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can find the code at the links I've pasted to avoid post spamming, but if anything else is needed, I'll surely provide it.